# Let user subscribe to specific categories

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

How could I let each user subscribe to a specific categories of his choice? I want to do something like reddit subscribe to categories? Is there any tutorial helps doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give them this url http://www.example.com/?cat=42&feed=rss2

This one if permalinks are enabled http://example.com/category/categoryname/feed

Replace the site url & also the cateogries id or slug with the correct one

### UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT

Display a list of categories to the user maybe with `wp_dropdown_categories`. Save the id of the category the user subscribed to in the database by using the function `add_user_meta()` or `update_user_meta`, then on the template on which you want to show the posts use `WP_Query` to retrieve all the posts.

If you don't know the functions, check out their reference on codex, it's easy to find on google

Comment: I don't want to let user subscribe by rss. I want to show him with wordpress loop content from categories he has subscribed to.

Comment: Edited the answer. I'm not familiar with Reddit, so assumed it was RSS by reading the word subscribe

Comment: @FerasOdeh did you ever get this up and running?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin "[post notification](http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-notification/)" that allows users to subscribe to posts in general or to specific categories (if you enable this option in the plugin settings). The user will be notified by email if a new post has been published. You can even create email templates. 
The plugin hasn't been updated for a while but still does an excellent job.